# Make TTY interrupt kill child process but not parent shell

Tags: linux, bash

There are 2 bash scripts:

- script.sh

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  # Set terminal interrupt signal to 'ctrl+]'
  stty intr ^]

  for i in $(seq 1 1000); do \
      echo $i;
      sleep 1;
  done;
  ```
- script_runner.sh

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo BEGIN
  ./script.sh
  echo END
  ```

Here is how it works:

- "script_runner.sh" runs "script.sh".
- "script.sh" running a loop and, at some execution point, "CTRL-]" is pressed.
- "intr" signal triggered and all shell scripts, including parent stop their jobs.

At the same time, I expect, that parent should continue to work and print "END".

How is it possible to implement?

P.S. I've tried to use "quit" signal instead of "intr" but I'm not sure if it is legal way to do so.

Comment: For the purpose of the question, changing the interrupt key from Control-C to Control-] just complicates things.

Comment: I could see using a different approach to terminating the script early -- *not* using the `intr` mechanism, but say, polling for enter to be available to read on stdin -- solving this cleanly.

Comment: Heck, at that point, you could have the parent process do all the work -- spawn the child in the background with its stdin disconnected from the TTY, wait for a carriage return, kill the child process; done.

Comment: It sounds like all you really want is for the parent to *not* terminate upon receipt of SIGINT.  So have the parent trap the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward SIGINT to your child processes. Change `script_runner.sh` in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

sigint () { kill -INT -$$; }
trap sigint INT

echo BEGIN
./script.sh
echo END
```

When `script_runner.sh` gets SIGINT, it forwards it to all processes in the process group. This terminates the child shell and `sleep`.

**Update**

As William commented, this is also sufficient:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap : INT

echo BEGIN
./script.sh
echo END
```

Comment: There is no need to forward the signal.  When the signal is sent, it goes to the foreground process group, which includes the process running script.sh.